# How do the ultra rich protect their money?

Tags: insurance, fdic, ultra-rich

FDIC insures each account up to $250,000.  A few billion / 250,000 = way too many bank accounts.  So how do the ultra rich insure their fortunes?

Comment: Some good answers on that possible duplicate, the main bit is that they don't have that much money sitting in banks.

Comment: Yes it is usually in assets and in businesses.

Comment: This is also why credit default swaps exist.  Even SIPC only covers assets up to about $500k in value ('about' becasue obviously assets fluctuate in value and you may disagree with the SIPC as to the value of your assets should it ever be relevant).  I have $x amount of assets at Institution A, I can buy credit default swaps from other institutions for a value of $x - SIPC/FIDC covered value to simply carry the insurance myself.

Comment: Many "rich" people might not have a lot of actual money, you know.  For instance, Bill Gates might have however many billion dollars worth of Microsoft stock, but perhaps keeping the stock (and thus control of the company) is more important to him than having a pile of cash.

Comment: The ultra rich don't hold much cash in banks as the rate of return is very small.